# Woocommerce decrease space between image and text in product description?

Tags: css, woocommerce, whitespace

I added “add to cart” button image over which I have put a link to checkout, image is located on top of my product description but spacing between image and text is too great is there any way to decrease it? Perhaps with CSS?

How “add to cart” button looks now:
      [image: before]

and how I would like for it to look like:
      [image: after]

Here is my code in the product description for the image/visual above:

```html
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-623" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/addtocart1-2.jpg" alt="" width="383" height="70" />
<ul>
    <li>FREE WORLDWIDE SHIPPING</li>
    <li>Delivery time: 9 to 18 days</li>
</ul>
```

Update:

Bottom margin is definitely a source of problem. I'm using SiteOrigin CSS plugin to edit my css but Konards code (answer below) is not working as expected, [you can see how it looks with Konards code and when I uncheck bottom margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moCLe.png) with inspect element (text is deformed as well even when I delete text part of the code).

And [here you can see how the code looks before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YytiJ.png) it's saved in SiteOrigin CSS (got some errors as well). 
And [here is the code](https://pastebin.com/tXdzgCGu) (begins at line 10)

Comment: Yes, you will need CSS. Please share the current CSS and HTML (or URL) to get further help.

Comment: One way to do this is *probably* to change `<ul>` to `<ul class="notopmargin">`. Then create a new style: `.notopmargin {margin-top: 0;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send image how it looks on website?

I tried do it with CSS:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-623" src="(your image url)" alt="" width="383" height="70" />
<ul>
    <li>FREE WORLDWIDE SHIPPING</li>
    <li>Delivery time: 9 to 18 days</li>
</ul>

<style>
img {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
li,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  line-height: 8px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is a reasonable answer for static HTML, but Wordpress and Woocommerce have tons of CSS that might need to be overridden.

Comment: Bottom margin is definitely a source of problem. I'm using SiteOrigin CSS plugin to edit my css but your code is not working as expected you can see how it looks with your code and when I uncheck bottom margin with inspect element at https://i.imgur.com/HxzMaiU.png (text is deformed as well even when I delete text part of the code). And here you can see how the code looks before and after it's saved in SiteOrigin CSS (got some errors as well) at https://i.imgur.com/gzqrc5u.png

Comment: And here is my whole css code in SiteOrigin CSS plugin (there is only short code to hide woocommeres add to cart button) at pastebin.com/q2pns3bJ